# Importing modules from a CMS in typescript, gives module not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, content-management-system, typescript-typings

When trying to import a module thats not in my node_modules Typescript tells me it cant find the module. The problem im facing is that the module is inside a CMS and i never get it as an actual module.

I can import it with es6 syntax, but behind the scenes its a Java API that returns javascript, and I can only call the functions without knowing 100% the structure of the code behind it (except the JavaDOC).

Ofcourse Typescript tries to import this as usual and cant find the module, example syntax: `import PropertyUtil from 'PropertyUtil'`, where PropertyUtil is the module.

Is there any way I can solve this? I have a workaround currently with building fake modules from the Javadoc but I dont find it reliable enough..

Comment: put a `// @ts-ignore` on top of the import line

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically? Or make TS ignore the files that it cant find?